# Spring boot camel integration test, CamelContext autowire fails

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-camel

I am writing unit test for Camel route. I need to use @SpringBootTest so that I can also use @TestPropertySource. I have several property file mapped property classes.

My test code looks like this

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = {CamelAutoConfiguration.class})
@RunWith(CamelSpringBootRunner.class)
@BootstrapWith(CamelTestContextBootstrapper.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application-test.yml")
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {ApplicationConfig.class, SFTPConfig.class, CamelTestContextBootstrapper.class})
@EnableConfigurationProperties
public class RouteBuilderTest
{

    @Autowired
    private CamelContext camelContext;
```

I have added below dependency also as I am using junit4 in project.

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
     <artifactId>camel-test-spring</artifactId>
     <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Autowiring of CamelContext fails. With standard spring error.

```
No qualifying bean of type 'org.apache.camel.CamelContext' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

Please help. Badly stuck on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple misused annotations in your test. Try this way:

```java
@RunWith(CamelSpringBootRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {ApplicationConfig.class, SFTPConfig.class})
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application-test.yml")
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
public class RouteBuilderTest
{
    @Autowired
    private CamelContext camelContext;
```

Comment: Hi, I tried this. But still not working :-(

Comment: What exactly is not working? Can you share a minimal reproducible example of your problem?